# Req.body is empty, express

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to make some client-server program using express. But no matter what I try req.body is always empty. I have searched for solutions, but the main problem in most cases is that 'Content-Type' or app.use(bodyParser.json()); are missing. I have got both, but it still doesn't work.

Here is my server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Here is client side:

```
const promise = fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000', {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept' : 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({x: 2, y:3}),
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "empty"? empty object? null? undefined? empty string? empty array?

Comment: {} is printed, when I expect something like this "{x: 2, y:3}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the **mode: 'no-cors'**. You won't be able to set the Accept and Context-Type headers.

Comment: But without using it browser gives me an error " Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.".

Comment: If you're making the request across a different domain than the javascript is being served, you'll need to send back an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. If you open your browser on 127.0.0.1 and make the request to that address, you won't need the CORS header. If you're using localhost to view the page, but sending the request to the ip address, you'll get the CORS error.

Comment: Or, send the data over using post params instead of json so that you don't have to change the content type.

Comment: I got it. I changed and now it works. Thank you very much.